# How to remove error code and print only message | PLSQL

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I have to print only error message and remove code number

```
BEGIN

IF :MY_TEXT is null THEN 
   raise_application_error(-20001,'Text field cannot be empty')
END IF;

Exception 
     when others then
             :MSG := replace(SQLERRM,'^ORA-+:','');

 
END;
```

**Expected output :**

```
Text filed cannot be empty
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use something like this ***SUBSTR(MSG, INSTR(MSG, ':', 1, 1)+2 )***

```sql
DECLARE
MY_TEXT VARCHAR2(100);
MSG VARCHAR2(100);

BEGIN

IF MY_TEXT is null THEN 
   raise_application_error(-20001,'Text field cannot be empty');
END IF;

Exception 
     when others then
             MSG := SQLERRM ;
             dbms_output.put_line( SUBSTR(MSG, INSTR(MSG, ':', 1, 1)+2 ) );
 
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also just change your REPLACE call to a REGEXP_REPLACE as it appears you were trying to use a regular expression to match the error:

```
:MSG := REGEXP_REPLACE(SQLERRM,'^ORA-[0-9]+: ', NULL);
```

Match a pattern of 'ORA-' at the start of the line, followed by 1 or digits, then a colon followed by a space and replace with NULL.

Note technically the ', NULL' is not needed in this call but including makes it clear to future maintainers what the intention is here and I would argue would be best practice.